# Intermittent HTTP 500 error returned to client

Tags: wcf, rest, iis, intermittent

Client gets intermittent http 500 error when calling our WCF based rest service. When we check our IIS (IIS 7.5) logs there are no http 500 errors matching the reported errors. Nothing is trapped in the service error logs. We are at a loss where the http 500 errors are coming from. If the IIS logs do not have a record and no exceptions in the service error logs, where else could the http 500 be generated from? This is happening intermittently for them which makes it even harder to troubleshoot. Any suggestions for how to track these kind of errors or what might typically cause a http 500 to be returned when nothing is found in the IIS logs?
IIS logs do show 500 errors just not for these specific reported ones.
Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might be able to get further information from a [WCF trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes we did set up WCF trace but there was no 500 error there.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a reverse proxy that could cause you trouble ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how that could cause the issue? The api calls works most of the time. Say out of calls made every half an hour by the client, 4-5 calls will fail in a day.